# How to make the last DataGrid's column occupy the whole left space?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

First!
I know it can seem a kind of [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389630/how-to-make-the-last-column-in-wpf-datagrid-take-all-the-left-space-always) nevertheless it isn't.

I have a grid as a data template for `DataGrid.RowDetails`.
It has three columns: two with `Width="Auto"` and the 3d with `Width="*"`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NotEmptyDistributionsTemplateKey">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SoftwareVersionDistributions}"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        CanUserResizeRows="False"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        RowHeaderWidth="0"
        Margin="20,5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Architecture" 
                Binding="{Binding SoftwareArchitecture.Name, TargetNullValue=Все, FallbackValue=Все}"
                Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Language" 
                Binding="{Binding SysCodepage.Title, TargetNullValue=Все, FallbackValue=Все}" 
                Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn 
                Header="Link" 
                Binding="{Binding DownloadLink}"
                Width="*" 
                CanUserResize="False"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This template shows exactly 3 columns, if Grid is nested in a cell.
But when it is used as `RowDetaislTemplate` 4th empty column appears.
This makes me mad.

Does anybody have ideas why this can happen?

**Update 1**. How it looks:

[image]

**Update 2**.

Finally I found the soultion. Just added `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`

Now it's ok:

[image]

But I cannot understand this odd behavior.

**Update 3** (may be helpful to someone)

Recently we've found a bug which our users had and the developers did not. The bug was again about DataGrid's width and alignment. Well, may be this was not really a bug, but we had different behavior of the control.
The research revealed that when installing .net framework 4.5 installer also updated .net framework 4.0. This update changed somehow DataGrid's behavior. (to the expected one)
We asked our users to install framework 4.5 and the problem dissapeared. Though our app still targets .net 4.0

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, I suspect the problem is the parent grid giving a * width column

Comment: @Charleh. You are right. The width of a column is *. But when this data template serves as a template for a cell everything works fine. RowDetailsTemplate is a problem.

Comment: @Charleh. I'll post screenshot tomorrow

Comment: @Charleh. It's getting more interesting=) I tried to reproduce the bug at home with simple markup and found that RowDetailsTemplate has unlimitied width. But in my real application it is somehow magically restricted and occupies exactly the width of ItemsPresenter.

Comment: What happens if you put the DataGrid that is in the DataTemplate inside of a Grid, or a StackPanel?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out what is going on.  The issue is similar to when a DataGrid has HorizontalAlignment=Stretch and not enough columns.  I would recomment either setting the width of the last column manually (which may not be practical) or binding each column's Width property to something in a ViewModel and then calculate the Width of the last column.  Or, if the DG doesn't have to take up the entire width of its container, make HorizontalAlignment=Left.

Comment: I think it is better if you write the answer as an answer. I missed that you had found a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found the soultion.

Just added `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`

For those who targets Framework v4.0
Recently we found a bug which our users had and the developers did not. The bug was again about DataGrid's width and alignment. Well, may be this was not really a bug but we had different behavior of the control.
The research revealed that when installing .net framework 4.5 installer also updated .net framework 4.0. This update changed somehow DataGrid's behavior. (to the expected one)
We asked our users to install framework 4.5 and the problem disappeared. Though our app still targets .net 4.0