# DataGrid Columns are not Resizing if not given with of the DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here I am doing the application as resolution independent. Up-to what I understand, if we want resolution independent we should not define Height and Width for the control. When I did not define the width of the DataGrid, the columns are not readable when I run the application, you can see it from the below fig...

[image]

And the DataGrid columns are not resizing.

When I give the width to the DataGrid, it is working fine. But the thing is, if we run the same application in the different resolution, DataGrid is not resizing.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" DataContext="{Binding CollectionDetails}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  RowHeaderWidth="0" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" MinWidth="800"  Margin="15" >
          <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding S_NO}" Header="SOURCE__ID" MinWidth="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding DOB}" Header="MISSION__ID" MinWidth="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding DOJ}" Header="MISSION__NAME" MinWidth="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding EMP_ID}" Header="START__TIME" MinWidth="300" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NAME}" Header="STATUS" MinWidth="150" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Consolidate"  Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="15" Width="90"  Height="26" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>

</Grid>
```

Can anybody give me the hint on how to solve the issue. 
I am working on VS15

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT**

**Solution** : I placed my userControl in ScrollViewer. So, by setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility= "Disabled"` works fine. Thanks....

Comment: I removed MinWidth in your textcolumn and the code work for me (in the sense that i can read all the header correctly). Are you sizing your UserControl/main window?

Comment: @DanieleSartori No, I removed all the MinWidth in DataGridTextColumns, but there is no change. I already checked.

Comment: Then you didn't gave us all the code and the problem is somewhere else. Cause i copy pasted your code, removed min width and everything work smoothly

Comment: The things are 2. You are either wrapping the datagrid in a control like a scrollviewer or you have set somewhere a width in a parent of this datagrid (like MainWindow/UserControl)

Comment: I have seen a similar issue with RowDetailsTemplate. see [why-width-doesnt-work-for-columns-in-datagrid-located-in-rowdetailstemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003449/why-width-doesnt-work-for-columns-in-datagrid-located-in-rowdetailstemplate)

Comment: @DanieleSartori ya I wrote this in userControl. I'll check it once what you told. Thanks

Comment: As @ASh mentioned, I placed my userControl in ScrollViewer. So, by setting 'ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility= "Disabled" ' works fine.