# WPF datagrid row details column width

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, row, width

I have a main datagrid with row details.  The row details expand to another datagrid as shown below.

Here is the question, in the main datagrid, I put * in the width in the column, e.g.

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="CUSTOMER" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding CUSTOMER_CODE, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It worked as it supposed to.  It automatically fills the empty space of the datagrid.

However, I put the same * in the width in the row detail datagrid DataGridTextColumn.  It seems to have absolutely no effect.  See screenshot.
[image]

Could some one help me please? Thank you!

Comment: What is the container of the second DataGrid? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003449/why-width-doesnt-work-for-columns-in-datagrid-located-in-rowdetailstemplate) help? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956023/how-to-make-the-last-datagrids-column-occupy-the-whole-left-space)?

Comment: OMG The link worked! Thank you so much.  I was looking for the answer for such a long time.  You are a saver!  Thank you!

Comment: No prob, I'm now flagging as a duplicate if you don't mind