# Wpf Datagrid Last Column Width=“*” with SizeToContent="Width" causes window to fill entire screen

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid that's within a window that needs to be able to resize to the window if some other element makes the window resize. Because the window needs to be able to resize itself to other elements changing size, I have to use SizeToContent="Width".

The grid's width is set to auto and it does everything perfectly until I set the width of the final column to "*" so that it fills the extra space. When the star column width and window ResizeToContent are used together, the window ends up becoming the full width of the viewable area. If I set the width of the grid to a specific size that it all works, but then the grid won't resize to fill.

How do I keep the window from resizing itself like this when using column widths of *?

I tried an attached property solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389630/how-to-make-the-last-column-in-wpf-datagrid-take-all-the-left-space-always), but I get the same result.

I was also able to fix the problem with a code behind hack that sets the MaxWidth on the datagrid to the width of the window minus the margins when the window is resized.  From debugging it seems it's a bug in the datagrid itself stemming from the empty space after the columns. When the grid resizes, the last column resizes to fill which pushes the bounds of the grid beyond it's current size which forces it to resize and so on until you hit the full view width.